# Print each element of a CArray

Tags: arrays, haskell

I have this [CArray](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/carray-0.1.6.8/docs/Data-Array-CArray.html#g:5)

```
import qualified Data.Array.CArray as CArr
import qualified Data.Array.IArray as IArr

arr :: CArr.CArray Int Double
arr = IArr.array (1, 4)  $ zip [1..4] [1..4]
```

How do I print each element of CArray? Something like this pseudocode if `arr` is a list:

```
mapM_ print arr
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mapM_ print (IArr.elems arr)
```

This looks like the easiest solution.